# Understanding instantiation in Swift - OOP

Tags: swift, oop

What is the difference between the following two examples?

I have always used method 1 but if there is no difference I actually like the second method better.

```
class Foo() {
    func doSomething() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

### Method 1

```
class Bar() {
    let foo = Foo()

    // first call
    foo.doSomething()
    // second call
    foo.doSomething()
}
```

### Method 2

```
class Bar() {
    // first call
    Foo().doSomething()
    // second call
    Foo().doSomething()
}
```

Comment: In #2 you're using two **different** Foo instances.

Comment: @pawello2222 - it’s what I thought but I wasn’t really sure. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In method 1, you're assigning an object in memory to your instantiation of Foo. Let's say you want to reuse it and ensure that you store any changes in the properties for that object.

Let's say Foo had a property that keeps track of an integer value and `doSomething()` manipulates that property, you'd want to retain that in memory, so storing it as a single instance is the path you want to go. Otherwise, that integer value would just get reset to whatever its default at initialization was.

But let's say `doSomething()` is just a function that does some computation without storing any values, it wouldn't really matter. Every time you call `Foo()` in method 2, you're calling a brand-new instance of Foo, so you cannot expect any of its properties to be retained across usage.

Answer (score 2):

In method 2, you create 2 separate instances of `Foo` and call `doSomething` on the separate instances.

If `Foo` is stateless, the results of calling `doSomething` 2x on the same instance or calling it on 2 different instances will be the same, however, if `Foo` has some mutable state, the results will differ.

Creating 2 different instances also has consequences on the memory usage (however since these are local variables, that should be fine in most cases).